# How to output iterations/progress of a while or watch loop on each interval?

Tags: linux, ssh, while-loop, command, output

I am running a command in SSH which I have set on a loop using either `watch` or `while`.

The code:

```
while sleep SECONDS; do command; done
```

or

```
watch -n SECONDS command
```

**Example:**

```
while sleep 5; do ls; done
```

What this will do in this example is it will run `ls` every 5 seconds indefinitely until either it is exited with CTRL+C or the terminal is closed.

In my use case I am using a different command (which happens to not have any ssh output), but the results remain the same.

Both of these commands will display nothing (in the case that the command does not call for an output unlike `ls` does), but the command is indeed executed every `x` seconds.

The thing is, I want to view an output at each execution.

For example,

```
root@server:~ # while sleep 5; do <command>; done
.. executed at 00:00:05
.. executed at 00:00:10
.. executed at 00:00:15
.. executed at 00:00:20
.. executed at 00:00:25
.. executed at 00:00:30
```

and so on and so forth every `x` seconds when the command was executed until it is stopped.

Ideally I would like it to print the text like above including current time executed.

I can't just add in a `printf` into it cause I tried that.

```
# this doesn't work
while sleep 5; do <command> printf "..."; done
```

where `...` is the output I want it to say at each execution. Problem is yes it prints but it screws up my command. I tried printf before the command too but then the command is not executed.

How then can I get it to give me a desired output so I don't just see a blank page? For 5 seconds it is easy to count. But when I get to higher times like every 120 seconds, it is much more challenging to track when it executed. An output with the time it executed each loop would be extremely helpful.

I am on CentOS 6 by the way.